# How can I both check the scanner contents of a file and use them to assign input without skipping data with nextLine?

Tags: java

The method should read the contents of a file line by line and add each line to the array list. It should end once it reaches a solitary "." (period) or no more lines.

The problem is that I can not figure a way to check the contents of the next line without skipping lines since I am using nextLine numerous times. *I am limited to the use of hasNext and nextLine.*

```
public static ArrayList<String> getList(Scanner in) {
 ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

 while(in.hasNext() && !in.nextLine().equals("."))
  {list.add(in.nextLine());}

return list;}
```

As written the output will skip lines to output lines 2, 4, 6 etc
when I need it to output 1,2,3,4 etc.

I am sure I am simply not seeing the way to solve the issue but any hints *specifically* on how to get it working by *reformatting* what I have with the methods listed are appreciated.

Comment: I am probably missing something in the "duplicate" thread since I don't really see how it relates to my question, as my question is specifically about how to reformat the code I have using the tools available to get the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store the line in a variable:

```
public static List<String> getList(Scanner in) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        if (line.equals(".")) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            list.add(line);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: The `else` isn't necessary.

Comment: But it makes the code easier to read, IMO.

Comment: I disagree but I'm not going to debate that. I just thought OP should know that it's optional.

Comment: I tried using what you gave me but it doesn't seem to output anything from the file I am reading in. I did figure out another way with the help of a friend here that works. I will fiddle around with the one you gave me and see if I am doing something wrong also. Thanks for the help.